# Using DOMDOCUMENT to pull JavaScript values

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to use DOM Document to pull javascript values?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datePickerDate = "October 14, 2014";

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // meetings datepicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif',
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        populate_meetings(dateText, 0)
      },
      dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
      minDate: new Date(2009, 0, 1), maxDate: 0
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date("October 14, 2014"));
    $('#datepicker').val("October 14, 2014");
  });
    //call on page load to get meetings and date
    populate_meetings("October 14, 2014", 15515);
</script>
```

this is output in the html so i know its there... and i want to read the date  so pull var datePickerDate = so it returns October 14, 2014

-- alittle more clarification---

im using domdocument to scrape a site and grab the html like so

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

//set the main page html code that will be resused
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// load html
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

within the html is some javascript that has a date in it.... i would like to grab that date and stick it in a veriable

populate meetings just populates a dropdown box with the dates

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is. Could you clarify this a bit more?

Comment: Why is PHP in the tags? What happens inside  `populate_meetings`?

Comment: I have edited the above to provide alittle more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute the javascript using PHP (obviously), so the best thing might be to grab the JS variable with a regular expression. Here's an example of how to do it using DOMXPath:

```
# create a new XPath object that will operate on the DOM that you've initialised
# in your code
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

# find all the script elements in the page
$scripts = $xp->query("//script");
foreach ($scripts as $s) {
    # see if there are any matches for var datePickerDate in the script node's contents
    if (preg_match('#var datePickerDate = "(.*?)"#', $s->nodeValue, $matches)) {
        # the date itself (captured in brackets) is in $matches[1]
        print_r($matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
October 14, 2014
```